# Invalid session id selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to write tests for google page and after running the first test (that has passed) i encountered the error for all the other tests:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

This is my code, i tried using wait before closing the driver but it didnt help:

```
class GoogleSearchPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.search_box = self.driver.find_element("name", "q")



class GoogleSearchTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.close()

    def test_search_box_visible(self):
        search_page = GoogleSearchPage(self.driver)
        self.assertTrue(search_page.search_box.is_displayed() and search_page.search_box.is_enabled())

    def test_search(self):
        search_page = GoogleSearchPage(self.driver)
        search_page.search("cats")
        results_page = GoogleResultsPage(self.driver)
        titles = results_page.get_result_titles()
        self.assertTrue("Cats - Wikipedia" in titles)

    def test_empty_search(self):
        search_page = GoogleSearchPage(self.driver)
        search_page.search("")
        results_page = GoogleResultsPage(self.driver)
        self.assertEqual(len(results_page.get_result_titles()), 0)


    def test_image_search(self):
        search_page = GoogleSearchPage(self.driver)
        search_page.search("cat images")
        images_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="q qs"][contains(text(),"Images")]')
        images_button.click()
        self.assertTrue("Google Images" in self.driver.title)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: You should read up on implicit waits and how they work. `self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)` doesn't actually wait when called. It sets the timeout for the life of the driver instance. That timeout only applies when you get an element off the page. You are calling `driver.close()`... are you intending to just close the open tab or completely quit the browser? I'm guessing you are closing the only open tab and then continuing to try to use `driver` when there are no tabs open.

Comment: Best practice when creating tests is to have one test run per browser instance. Basically each test should follow these steps: 1. create browser instance, 2. run test, 3. `driver.quit()`. If you aren't doing this, I would suggest you rewrite your suite to follow this pattern.